# C# The best way to handle UNIX permissions from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, unix, permissions, unix-socket

Hey all I wanted to be able to set permissions on unix sockets for a project I am developing, I could find no 'nice' way to do is to I wrote this small namespace, it seems fairly effective so I decided to post here, see what everyone though and if there is anything I could improve.

Also for somewhere public if anyone else is looking for something to do it :)

You can use this solution to set permissions on files in a unix file system like thus:

```
UnixFileInfo UnixFilePermission = new Mono.Unix.UnixFileInfo(@"/somepath");
UnixFilePermission.FileAccessPermissions = new PermGrid().ConvertPerm(644);
```

And here is the namespace its self

```
using System;
using Mono.Unix;
using UnixTools;

namespace UnixTools
{
    public class PermGrid
    {
        private static readonly FileAccessPermissions[,] PermissionGrid = new FileAccessPermissions[3, 8] {
            {
                0x00,
                FileAccessPermissions.UserExecute,
                FileAccessPermissions.UserRead,
                FileAccessPermissions.UserExecute | FileAccessPermissions.UserRead,
                FileAccessPermissions.UserWrite,
                FileAccessPermissions.UserWrite | FileAccessPermissions.UserExecute,
                FileAccessPermissions.UserWrite | FileAccessPermissions.UserRead,
                FileAccessPermissions.UserReadWriteExecute
            },
            {
                0x00,
                FileAccessPermissions.GroupExecute,
                FileAccessPermissions.GroupRead,
                FileAccessPermissions.GroupExecute | FileAccessPermissions.GroupRead,
                FileAccessPermissions.GroupWrite,
                FileAccessPermissions.GroupWrite | FileAccessPermissions.GroupExecute,
                FileAccessPermissions.GroupWrite | FileAccessPermissions.GroupRead,
                FileAccessPermissions.GroupReadWriteExecute
            },
            {
                0x00,
                FileAccessPermissions.OtherExecute,
                FileAccessPermissions.OtherRead,
                FileAccessPermissions.OtherExecute | FileAccessPermissions.OtherRead,
                FileAccessPermissions.OtherWrite,
                FileAccessPermissions.OtherWrite | FileAccessPermissions.OtherExecute,
                FileAccessPermissions.OtherWrite | FileAccessPermissions.OtherRead,
                FileAccessPermissions.OtherReadWriteExecute
            },
        };
        public FileAccessPermissions ConvertPerm(int UnixPerm)
        {
            return ConvertPerm(UnixPerm.ToString());
        }
        public FileAccessPermissions ConvertPerm(String UnixPerm)
        {
            Int16 PermissionSegment = 0;
            Int16[] PermissionSegmentGroup = new Int16[3] { 0, 0, 0 };

            foreach (Char PermInt in UnixPerm)
            {
                PermissionSegmentGroup[PermissionSegment] = Convert.ToInt16(PermInt.ToString());
                PermissionSegment++;
            }
            return ConvertPerm(PermissionSegmentGroup);
        }
        public FileAccessPermissions ConvertPerm(Int16[] UnixPerm)
        {
            FileAccessPermissions PermStore = new FileAccessPermissions();
            PermStore = PermissionGrid[0, UnixPerm[0]] | PermissionGrid[1, UnixPerm[1]] | PermissionGrid[2, UnixPerm[2]];

            return PermStore;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unix uses two bytes while you are using 24 bytes.

Comment: Ah true it does seem rather effective though, I will have to take a closer look

Comment: Is this working fully? Did you ever find any other way of setting permissions for UNIX within C#? Btw, great job